# Custom Debian repo, why won't packages install by default?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I'm setting up a custom Debian repo for bespoke packages and I've got the repo up and am able to install and upgrade packages from it, but they don't install by default.

The behavior I would like is that when this repo is added and `apt update` run, that `apt update` will report there are new packages to install and `apt upgrade` will install them by default.

The behavior I have is that `apt update` updates the cache to reflect the new package, but I have to `apt install package-name` to install it.  If the package is installed and I update the repo with a newer version then `apt update` correctly reports an upgrade is available and `apt upgrade` will upgrade it; it's just new packages that don't work the way I expect them to.

I've tried `Standard` and `Required` priority in the .deb, and verified that's reflected in the Packages index file.

What tweak am I missing to make a package install by default from my repo?

Comment: Your packages need to be a newer version than available in other repos and the repo's release file needs to not include `NotAutomatic yes` (pin priority 1) or `ButAutomaticUpgrades yes` (pin priority 100).

Comment: Thank you @jordanm but package ("`setwise`") does not exist in other repos and neither `NotAutomatic` nor `ButAutomaticUpgrades` show up in the Release file.

Comment: I guess I misread the question. So you want `apt <something???>` to install every package available from your repo?

Comment: @jordanm correct - this will be the team's custom tools repo; we'd like to load all our custom tools on a box by default... when we set up a box, we specify our repo, we `apt update` and then either `apt install` or `apt upgrade` to install everything in the repo.  What I've got right now requires me to know all the packages in our custom repo and `apt install packagename` for each of them, which will get less workable as more packages get added.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that with `apt` or `apt-get` at all, unless you create a metapackage that depends on all your other package. You can however do this with aptitude via something like `aptitude install '~Ayourarchivename'`

Comment: One a side note, you should consider a configuration management system such as ansible.

Comment: @jordanm 1) The aptitude method works and would suffice for our needs - care to write that up as an answer?  2) Ansible would be nice but connectivity is very limited for these boxes - it's an ugly setup.